# AngularJS: How to use a JS script in a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular and am re-writing a application to use Angular. I have a few custom JS scripts that I need to use in my application and I have read that no DOM manipulations should exist outside a directive. But I am confused as to how I actually use this script in a directive.

The directive is supposed to fill a bar depending on the percent.

Here is my script that I need to wrap in a angular directive:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.level-bar-inner').css('width', '0');

$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.level-bar-inner').each(function() {    
        var itemWidth = $(this).data('level');

        $(this).animate({
            width: itemWidth
        }, 800);           
    });
});
```

This is how I have currently tried to implement it into my directive:

```
dcx.directive("dataPercent", [function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, el, atts){
            atts.css('width', '0');

        $(window).on('load', function() {
            el.each(function() {
                var itemWidth = $(this).data('level');
                el.animate({
                    width: itemWidth
                }, 800);
            });
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

And how I am calling it inside my HTML element:

```
<div class="level-bar-inner" data-percent="50%">
```

Its not working and im know it will be because I have not implemented it properly in my directive but I really dont know what I am doing wrong.

I have read the angular docs but still dont get it

Comment: Other issues aside (which have been aptly addressed in the answers), I don't think naming your directive `dataPercent` is a good idea because the  `data-percent` on your `div` is likely perceived by the browser as a `data-` attribute and it won't even call your directive.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
dcx.directive("dataPercent", [function(){
    return{
           restrict: 'A',
           scope: {
                itemWidth: "=",
            },
           link: function(scope, el, atts){
                el.css('width', '0');
                var render = function () {
                    animateWidth(el,scope);

                };
                render ();
                scope.$watch("itemWidth", render,true);

         }
     }

    function animateWidth(element,scope)
    {
             $(element).animate({
                    width: scope.itemWidth
                }, 800);
     }

}]);
```

Inside html-

```
<div class="level-bar-inner" data-percent item-width="50%">
```

I hope, this may help you.

Comment: You need to use @ in the isolated scope for this. Also watching the item width is not required by the OP. The script is only for adjusting the element one time.

Answer (score 0):

You have understood Angular correctly so far with minor gaps to be filled.

1. The directive code will be executed every time Angular finds a directive. So, you don't need to find all directive elements via JQuery and change them inside a single directive.

   ```
     dcx.directive("dataPercent", [function($timeout){
       return{
          link: function(scope, el, atts){

                 //Use timeout to make sure the code executes after DOM is loaded
                 $timeout(function() {
                     el.css('width', '0');    

                     var itemWidth = el.data('level');

                     //We use JQuery here for animations
                     $(el).animate({
                         width: itemWidth
                     }, 800);
                 }); 
            }
        }
   }]);
   ```

The above directive is found for every DOM markup it is cited

```
<div class="level-bar-inner" data-percent data-level="50%">
```

You should notice few things.

1. We use `$timeout` to make sure that your function executes only when the DOM is loaded
2. `el` is [JQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) and it doesn't have animate function. So I use Jquery here. But you can do it with [Angular animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

Comment: Is there an extra `});` in there?

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.